# Bridge on a bonded interface with systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, linux-networking, bridge, systemd-networkd, ifupdown

So I recently changed my server from a Debian based distribution that used the old
ifupdown style configs over to systemd-networkd.

What I want is, my two primary interfaces, bonded, and then a bridge attached to that bonded interface.

There will be an interface on the bridge, for the server, in the below example this is `bridge0.2`. The intention is that the host can communicate with guests operating on `bridge0`. VMs, and containers might be attached to `bridge0`. They may be on whatever VLAN they choose.

With that I had this configuration:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth1 inet manual

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
  bond-slaves eth0 eth1
  bond-mode 802.3ad
  bond-xmit-hash-policy layer2+3

auto bridge0
iface bridge0 inet manual
  bridge-ports bond0
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0
  bridge-vlan-aware yes
  bridge-vids 2-4094

auto bridge0.2
iface bridge0.2 inet static
  address 192.168.2.253/24
  gateway 192.168.2.1
```

I've tried to repeat the same thing with systemd-networkd. I can get VLAN 2 up on a bonded interface, but I can't seem to get the VLAN on the bridge up.

If I do `DHCP=true` on the `bridge0` interface, I can an address via `VLAN=1`. This makes me think there's some issue with the VLAN exiting the bridge.

I've tried for *far too long* to get this to work, and I really don't know what other combination to try. Here is what I have:

**10-all-nic-to-bond0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=eno1 eno2
Type=ether

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

**20-bond0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
MIIMonitorSec=1s
LACPTransmitRate=fast
UpDelaySec=2s
DownDelay=8s
TransmitHashPolicy=layer2+3
```

**20-bond0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=bond0

[Network]
BindCarrier=eno1 eno2
Description=Unconfigured bond interface
Bridge=bridge0
```

**30-bridge0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=bridge0
Kind=bridge

[Bridge]
VLANFiltering=false
STP=false
```

**30-bridge0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=bridge0

[Network]
VLAN=vlan2

[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=2-4094
```

**40-vlan2.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=vlan2
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=2
```

**40-vlan2.network**

```
[Match]
Name=vlan2

[Network]
Description=VLAN for direct access to gateway
DHCP=true

#[Address]
#Address=192.168.253/24
#DNS=192.168.2.1

#[Route]
#Gateway=192.168.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this working, it was `VLANFiltering=true` that was causing the issues, changing this to false allowed me to exit the bridge on VLAN2.